# Google Interactive Media Ads for tvOS

Tags: objective-c, tvos, google-ima

I am using Google Interactive Media Ads in my iOS application. It's working good and now I want to use them in my tvOS application. When I add the code for the Google Interactive Media Ads I am getting these issues:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteNotification
>   imaMessage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe4d9e0cb20'

and I am using this code for playing the ad:

```
- (void)requestAdsPre:(NSString *)url {
    self.adPlayerLayer = nil;
    //[self.contentPlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self setupAdsLoader];

    [self setUpAdDisplayContainer];
    // Create an ad request with our ad tag, display container, and optional user context.
    IMAAdsRequest *request =
    [[IMAAdsRequest alloc] initWithAdTagUrl:url
                         adDisplayContainer:self.adDisplayContainer
                                userContext:nil];
    [self.adsLoader requestAdsWithRequest:request];
}

#pragma mark SDK Setup

- (void)setupAdsLoader {
    self.adsLoader = [[IMAAdsLoader alloc] initWithSettings:nil];
    self.adsLoader.delegate = self;
}

- (void)setUpAdDisplayContainer {
    self.adDisplayContainer =
    [[IMAAdDisplayContainer alloc] initWithAdContainer:self.videoView companionSlots:nil];
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to use Google Interactive Media Ads for tvOS? Google Interactive Media Ads are working for both iOS and tvOS apps.

Comment: Have you tried to use Google IMA SDK for tvOS? I think you published your question on the day it was released.

Answer (score 1):

Google Interactive Media Ads [do not support tvOS](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/community?place=msg%2Fima-sdk%2FNWwQmfmmIkY%2Fo8j2TWFxJgAJ).

> Currently the IMA SDK does not support tvOS. If this changes, we will
>   make an announcement on our [blog](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/search/label/ima_sdk) and add a note on the release page.

The only tvOS advertising framework I'm aware of at the moment is [AppLovin](https://applovin.com/).

Comment: First version of Google Interactive Media Ads for tvOS was released at 5/9/2016.